# How to write specific rule for a target in makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I know the title is quite ambiguous but I just don't know how to describe my problem concisely. Please edit that if you want.

Currently my makefile is like the following:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

TARGET = foobar
SRC_FILES = foo.cpp bar.cpp main.cpp
OBJ_FILES := $(SRC_FILES:.cpp=.o)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.cpp %.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(TARGET)
```

The problem is that this structure requires `main.cpp` to have a `main.h` header file, which I don't really have. How can I handle this nicely?

Comment: Remove `%.h` from the `%.o: %.cpp %.h` line. You only need that to have your `.o` file rebuilt if the matching `.h` file changes (but the `.cpp` file doesn't).

Comment: @Etan I occasionally have to modify the header files only, for example change the value of a `#define CONSTANT`. So I want it to be recompiled even if only header files are changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC (and probably Clang) can build a list of dependencies for you; This way, you can simply make your object files from their source (cpp) file:

```
depend: .depend

.depend: $(SRC_FILES)
        rm -f ./.depend
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $^ -MF  ./.depend;

include .depend

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

You might also find interest in the [`makedepend`](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0/makedepend.1.html) tool.